# Unbound breakpoints in VSCode | React

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-debugger

I am trying to debug my react application auth.js file, however, the debug points are unbound.

My project structure is as follows:
The file which I am trying to debug (auth.js) is under this folder.

[image: auth.js]

However, all the Frontend codes are in a different folder named: "Frontend".

Therefore, to start the react project, it is required to go inside the path: Frontend/sprint and then enter: **npm start**.
[image: Frontend]

However, when I turn my project in debugger mode, in order to debug the auth.js, the breakpoints are unbound.

My launch.json file is attached here below.
[image: launch.json]

Further, the debug console is showing the following error:
[image: cosnole]

Is there any possible way to fix this debugging issue